# Node.js Waiting for data to return before module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, module, synchronous

I have a module that queries a database using a pool. The pool is created in a different module.

db.js

```
const dbPool = require('./pool.js');
dbPool.query(...);
```

pool.js

```
const getPWrd = () => {
  return [get password from key vault];
}
const getDBPool = () => {
    const password = getPWrd();
    const dbPoolPre = mysql.createPool({
        host,
        database,
        user,
        password,
        connectionLimit: 10,
        ssl: {
            rejectUnauthorized: true,
            ca: serverCa,
        },
    });
    return dbPoolPre;
};

const dbPool = getDBPool();
module.exports = dbPool;
```

If I hard code the password this code works fine. But I need to get the password (in this case from a key vault), and nothing I have tried can force the module to wait for the password to return before it exports. The pool is returned with the password empty or as an unresolved promise, depending on how I get the password.

I have tried using promises, async await, old fashioned functions, exporting a function that creates the pool or the pool itself.

Comment: Promises should be the answer here, but we'd have to see HOW you used promises.

Comment: Without ES13 top-level `await` in an ES module, there's nothing better you can do than export an unresolved promise. Simply wait for it everywhere you need the pool.

Comment: I am pretty sure that if promises should work that I did not use them the right way. Can you provide basic promise code that would work in this situation?

Comment: Instead of doing `await dbPool.query(…)` as usual, it basically becomes `await (await dbPool).query(…)`.